# Screen recording without third-party software on Windows 7?

Tags: screen-capture

Is there a way to do screen recording on Windows 7 without installing third-party software? (Doing it with Microsoft software would be okay.)

Specifically, I'd like to be able to run a program and generate a video file (for example, .avi) of the session. These would be short 30 second or so clips.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is Problem Steps Recorder.

You can access it by clicking the Start button and typing "psr.exe" and hitting enter.

This tool will record each mouse-click and save it as an image, then compile everything into HTML (more specifically, a Microsoft MHT file). However this is **not** a video capture tool. As far as I know, there isn't one built-in to Windows.

You may look into downloading the free [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/). With VLC, you can use your desktop as a capture device:

1. Click Media
2. Click Open Capture Device
3. Choose Capture Mode: Desktop (at this point, you may want to set a higher FPS)

..and then stream it to a file:

4. Click the arrow icon to the right of play, and click "Stream"
5. Leave the default "Source: screen://" and click "Next"
6. Select "File" in the dropdown and click "Add"
7. Choose a filename then click "Next"
8. Choose your encoding and then click "Next"
9. Click "Stream"

Hope this helps.

Comment: VLC for capturing screen is really annoying

Comment: VLC is really a great option unless you need to track mouse movement and events and/or track multiple screens

Comment: More information on screen capture with VLC: http://superuser.com/questions/261167/how-do-i-capture-a-video-of-my-windows-7-desktop-in-vlc

Comment: @Travis I tried this several times with different encoders. I have to uncheck "Activate transcoding" or they crash.

Answer (score 25):

Well.

You asked for "without third party software". I suggest you Microsoft´s Expression Encoder 4. There´s a limited free version that captures the screen for 10 minutes.

Comment: It's even better: With Expression Encoder 4 SP2, the time limit has been removed!

Comment: Get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870

Comment: @MichaelS. the download link is no longer available

Comment: Now I recommend OBS instead.

Answer (score 15):

You can use "Screenrecorder" which is a utility from Microsoft, based on Windows Media Encoder.

It's not included by default in Windows, but can be downloaded from [this Microsoft Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx).

Comment: It records into WMV. Unfortunately it doesn't show mouse clicks on the record in any way. Just the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) in the past. You could install it elsewhere, copy to a USB drive, and use it portably from there?

Comment: CamStudio has become malicious software:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamStudio#Malicious_software

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is specifically *installing* third-party software, you can use [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) to connect to your Windows 7 box from another PC that does have recording software installed, and record just the Remote Desktop Connection window.