# Screen-Sharing Options for Student/Tutor?

Tags: networking, microsoft-virtual-pc, screen-capture

I used to use [GoToMeeting](http://gotomeeting.com) about a year ago, but that was too expensive at $49/mo.

Some things I liked about it (in the context of learning computing) include:

- I could give point/click access to a user ...and quickly take it a way.
- My mouse would override their mouse.
- I could record a video of the session which was handy for complex configurations of software, etc. for later review (tutors charge by the hour).

I have very briefly searched Google to find a few competitors; one is free. You could discuss any competing service. The question is how do they compare? And, what was your person experience like?

- [ShowMyPC](http://showmypc.com/) ~$14/mo
- [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/) ~$49/mo
- [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com/index.jsp) Free for private use
- [a short list](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-easy-screen-sharing-and-remote-access-tools-all-free/)

Comment: Please note, Super User is not a duscussion forum - refer  [faq#dontask].

Comment: Sathya, I apologize. I can see how aspects of this are very subjective. I will think harder about specific non-subjective questions pertaining to this issue IF I should ask again.

Answer (score 0):

VNC should probably allow most of this for any OS, though recording is a little tricky  - [UVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) seems to be a possible varient - it has a [screen recorder](http://www.uvnc.com/screenrecorder/)

Alternately you could look at remote assistance (if both boxes are windows) and use [vlc](https://superuser.com/questions/261167/how-do-i-capture-a-video-of-my-windows-7-desktop-in-vlc/267277#267277) to record